# Is it possible to send tvp parameter using DbParameter

Tags: design-patterns, ado.net, sqlclient

I know we can use `SqlParameter` and `SqlDbType.Structured` to pass tvp parameters to a stored procedures. But is it possible with `DbParameter`? `DbParameter`'s `DbType` doesn't have `structured` enum value.

Instead of using `SqlClient` provider, I'm trying to use provider mentioned in config file. So I'm trying to use base classes instead of SQL derived classes.

Comment: No that isn't possible, because table-valued parameters are a **SQL Server** specific feature - so they only exist in the `SqlClient` namespace - this is not a generally available feature supported by all implementors of the generic versions

Comment: Thank you so much @marc_s for your reply.